# How to get contacts interaction history in Windows Phone 7 Mango?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I read this demo about accessing contact data

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286416(v=vs.92)#BKMK_Accessing

but would it be possible to get the interaction history, like when you view the contact details in the People Hub, you get the history page and you'll get the previous interactions like calls, mails, etc.

 I understand WP has few sandboxing restrictions but 
Would it be possible to get the interaction history like last call duration, etc on a contact by contact basis atleast ?

Also I understand WP does not have any event for incoming call alerts but
say I want to get the number/duration of the current call after the call is finished when the app is in the background (without intercepting the call) is that allowed ? If so how ?

Any indication it would come in future versions like WP8 ?

Answer (score 0):

**No**, you can't access User Call History in WP7^. There is no API to retrieve Call History.

There in **No Sign** that MS will allow developers access to "Call history" in near future.
Some of the Changes that will be in WP8 SDK are [here](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/06/29/recapping-windows-phone-8-developer-news.aspx), and none of them is related to the Call History issue.

*Unless that call is made using the App itself, even then you can only have the number called not the exact time of call.